# Extrude a concave, complex polygon in PyVista

Tags: python, cad, pyvista

I wish to take a concave and complex (containing holes) polygon and extrude it 'vertically' into a polyhedron, purely for visualisation. I begin with a shapely [`Polygon`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html?highlight=Polygon#Polygon), like below:

```py
poly = Polygon(
    [(0,0), (10,0), (10,10), (5,8), (0,10), (1,7), (0,5), (1,3)], 
    holes=[
        [(2,2),(4,2),(4,4),(2,4)],
        [(6,6), (7,6), (6.5,6.5), (7,7), (6,7), (6.2,6.5)]])
```

which I correctly plot (reorientating the exterior coordinates to be clockwise, and the hole coordinates to be counterclockwise) in matplotlib as:

[image]

I then seek to render this polygon extruded out-of-the-page (along `z`), using [PyVista](https://docs.pyvista.org/). There are a few hurdles; PyVista doesn't directly support concave (nor complex) input to its [`PolyData`](https://docs.pyvista.org/api/core/_autosummary/pyvista.PolyData.html) type. So we first create an extrusion of simple (hole-free) concave polygons, as per [this discussion](https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista/discussions/2398).

```py
def extrude_simple_polygon(xy, z0, z1):

    # force counter-clockwise ordering, so PyVista interprets polygon correctly
    xy = _reorient_coords(xy, clockwise=False)

    # remove duplication of first & last vertex
    xyz0 = [(x,y,z0) for x,y in xy]
    if (xyz0[0] == xyz0[-1]):
        xyz0.pop()

    # explicitly set edge_source
    base_vert = [len(xyz0)] + list(range(len(xyz0)))
    base_data = pyvista.PolyData(xyz0, base_vert)
    base_mesh = base_data.delaunay_2d(edge_source=base_data)
    vol_mesh  = base_mesh.extrude((0, 0, z1-z0), capping=True)

    # force triangulation, so PyVista allows boolean_difference
    return vol_mesh.triangulate()
```

Observe this works when extruding the outer polygon and each of its internal polygons in-turn:

```py
extrude_simple_polygon(list(poly.exterior.coords), 0, 5).plot()
```

[image]

```py
extrude_simple_polygon(list(poly.interiors[0].coords), 0, 5).plot()
extrude_simple_polygon(list(poly.interiors[1].coords), 0, 5).plot()
```

[image]
[image]

I reasoned that to create an extrusion of the original *complex* polygon, I could compute the [`boolean_difference`](https://docs.pyvista.org/api/core/_autosummary/pyvista.PolyDataFilters.boolean_difference.html#pyvista.PolyDataFilters.boolean_difference). Alas, the result of

```
outer_vol = extrude_simple_polygon(list(poly.exterior.coords), 0, 5)
for hole in poly.interiors:
    hole_vol = extrude_simple_polygon(list(hole.coords), 0, 5)
    outer_vol = outer_vol.boolean_difference(hole_vol)

outer_vol.plot()
```

is erroneous:

[image]

The doc advises to inspect the normals via [`plot_normals`](https://docs.pyvista.org/api/core/_autosummary/pyvista.PolyData.plot_normals.html), revealing that all extruded volumes have inward-pointing (or else, unexpected) normals:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The [`extrude`](https://docs.pyvista.org/api/core/_autosummary/pyvista.PolyData.extrude.html) doc mentions nothing of the extruded surface normals nor the original object (in this case, a polygon) orientation.

We could be forgiven for expecting our polygons must be *clockwise*, so we set `clockwise=True` in the first line of `extrude_simple_polygon` and try again. Alas, `PolyData` now  misinterprets our base polygon; calling `base_mesh.plot()` reveals (what *should* look like our original blue outer polygon):

[image]

with extrusion

[image]

- Does PyVista always expect counter-clockwise polygons?
- Why does extrude create volumes with inward-pointing surface normals?
- How can I correct the extruded surface normals?
- Otherwise, how can I make PyVista correctly visualise what should be an incredibly simply-extruded concave complex polygon??

Comment: `.flip_normals()` forces the normals to become outward facing, although the problem persists. It is likely `boolean_difference` is not triggering a remesh, so the difference is described using the extremely coarse triangulation

Comment: Minor pedantry remark: 2 out of 3 of your "simple (hole-free) convex polygons" are concave.

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні quite right, I've corrected them to prevent confusion in future readers

Answer (score 4):

You're very close. What you have to do is use a *single* call to [`delaunay_2d()`](https://docs.pyvista.org/api/core/_autosummary/pyvista.PolyDataFilters.delaunay_2d.html) with all three polygons (i.e., the enclosing one and the two holes) as edge source (loop source?). It's also important to have faces (rather than lines) from each polygon; this is what makes it possible to enforce the holeyness of the holes.

Here's a complete example for your input (where I manually flipped the orientation of the holes; you seem to have a `_reorient_coords()` helper that you should use instead):

```py
import pyvista as pv

# coordinates of enclosing polygon
poly_points = [
    (0, 0), (10, 0), (10, 10), (5, 8), (0, 10), (1, 7), (0, 5), (1, 3),
]
# hole point order hard-coded here; use your _reorient_coords() function
holes = [
    [(2, 2), (4, 2), (4, 4), (2, 4)][::-1],
    [(6, 6), (7, 6), (6.5, 6.5), (7, 7), (6, 7), (6.2, 6.5)][::-1],
]

z0, z1 = 0.0, 5.0

def points_2d_to_poly(points, z):
    """Convert a sequence of 2d coordinates to a polydata with a polygon."""
    faces = [len(points), *range(len(points))]
    poly = pv.PolyData([p + (z,) for p in points], faces=faces)
    return poly

# bounding polygon
polygon = points_2d_to_poly(poly_points, z0)

# add all holes
for hole_points in holes:
    polygon += points_2d_to_poly(hole_points, z0)

# triangulate poly with all three subpolygons supplying edges
# (relative face orientation is critical here)
polygon_with_holes = polygon.delaunay_2d(edge_source=polygon)

# extrude
holey_solid = polygon_with_holes.extrude((0, 0, z1 - z0), capping=True)
holey_solid.plot()
```

[image: screenshot of perspective view of the expected extruded "volume"]

Here's the top view of the polygon pre-extrusion:

```py
plotter = pv.Plotter()
plotter.add_mesh(polygon_with_holes, show_edges=True, color='cyan')
plotter.view_xy()
plotter.show()
```

[image: top view of polygon showing holes where expected, and the edges of the triangulation elsewhere]

Comment: Any idea why this breaks for the below simple, convex (crooked cross-shaped) polygon? It seems to discard a vertex, interpolating an edge between to non-adjacent vertices. `poly_points = [(227.0, 119.0), (216.910083959346, 343.61030490499337), (349.0, 348.0), (333.0, 444.0), (212.50063243106501, 441.76853023020493), (204.0, 631.0), (93.0, 632.0), (95.0, 625.0), (100.03766532489936, 439.68588269120187), (9.0, 438.0), (18.0, 337.0), (102.75255979697455, 339.8165503255792), (109.0, 110.0)]`

Comment: I've resolved the above bug (the superfluous specification of the final vertex as the first, + needing to ensure the coordinate list does not have its own superfluous final vertex repeat), and edited it into your answer

Comment: @AntiEarth sorry, I couldn't check this on a laptop sooner. Thanks for the bugfix, the repetition of the first point was because I originally defined lines rather than faces, and you need to come back to the first point if you want a cosed line. But since we need _faces_ this was a mistake. I can confirm that with the updated `faces` definition your cross example works.

Comment: This solution fails for `poly_points = [(389.0, 78.0, 230), (389.0, 784.0, 230), (-1021.0, 784.0, 230), (-1021.0, 78.0, 230)]`, and `hole1_points = [(-396.0, 190.0, 230), (-396.0, 350.0, 230), (-350.0, 350.0, 230), (-350.0, 649.0, 230), (-201.0, 649.0, 230), (-201.0, 350.0, 230), (-152.0, 350.0, 230), (-152.0, 190.0, 230)]`, and `hole2_points = [(-653.0, 201.0, 230), (-653.0, 649.0, 230), (-499.0, 649.0, 230), (-499.0, 201.0, 230)]`.

Without extrusion, [this](https://pasteboard.co/nr3sVzUvVFsm.png) is erroneously rendered as [this](https://pasteboard.co/SdTCYjLCzfsW.png)

Any idea why?

Comment: @AntiEarth sorry for the late reply, life's been very busy. If I shift the first hole with +100 along the x axis it starts to work. It looks like the triangulation is ill-conditioned there (there's also a VTK warning in this case). I could fix the problem by making the hole definitions have denser points along the line. One way to do this is with `import numpy as np`, then `scale = np.linspace(0, 1, 2, endpoint=False)[:, None]; holes = [[p for p1, p2 in zip(hole, hole[1:]) for p in p2*scale + p1*(1 - scale)] + [hole[-1]] for hole in holes]`. This doubles the density.

Comment: Using `np.linspace(0, 1, 10)` would give you 10x as many points along each hole contour. To be clear, in the previous comment `holes = [hole1_points, hole2_points]` according to your comment.

Comment: No need to apologise - you've been a fantastic help! Manually refining the mesh worries me, since I use PyVista for 3D visualisation within a user-facing Python library, and need something completely robust. My polyhedra (as described above) are vertically-extruded polygons specified as vertices, and their base polygons render fine in matplotlib. Is PyVista the wrong tool to render their 3D extrusions? In fact, my library creates meticulous conformal meshes and PyVista is used to visualise the "base symbolic scene", *not* the (numerically damaged) mesh. Are there non-mesh-based renderers?

Comment: @AntiEarth the extrusions would be fine, where this breaks (and it's VTK doing the breaking, not PyVista) is the triangulation of the 2d base before extrusion. Once you have a proper polygon I'd expect extrusion to Just Work^TM. But in any case I don't really have experience in this regard, and in the broader field. E.g. I'm not sure what "non-mesh-based renderer" might mean. You should consider [asking on the PyVista github discussions page](https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista/discussions) where more eyes and of much broader backgrounds can chime in.

Comment: Seems so - I've created an [Issue](https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista/issues/4097), and will update this question with any progress. By "non-mesh-based renderer", I mean any facility which lets me specify complex polygons by their coordinates and render them faithfully, without having to perform explicit meshing or tweaking, nor project the coordinates into a (more) approximate subspace.